# how to generate tables from spring components with spring-mybatis?

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis

I'm using spring-mybatis and I have configured many components and mappers.
My services are working without any problems but i want to know if is it possible to generate tables from spring component (using annotations `@Component`) or if I have to Create tables manually so I can execute my mappers methods ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following method to do this, but maybe it's a bit hacky.

Create your mapper as normal, but add another interface method to create the table:

```
@Insert("create table if not exists students (name integer)")
public void createTable();
```

Then, in your service class, create a method with the `@PostContruct`annotation so that it gets called at startup:

```
@Autowired
private StudentDao studentMapper;

@PostConstruct
private void setup() {
    // setup stuff goes here.
    studentMapper.createTable();
    // include any other mappers you have...
}
```

I tried annotating the `createTable()` method with `@PostConstruct`but it wasn't executed. Probably because it is an interface.

Hope that helps
Owen